# Host ASP.NET Core webservices as part of another application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am building an windows service that manages several tasks in the background. To manage these tasks and see progress and status I thought it should be possible to add some kind of webapi that exposes the service its state and allows for starting, stopping and submitting tasks.

But though I can find many sites telling me how to host an asp.net core application as a (windows) service. I can't seem to google the correct information that tells me the correct way to bolt a webservice to an existing application. The difference being that the web-interface would be one of several interfaces into and not the primary base of the application (i.e. I'm not looking for backgroundtasks inside a webapp). Thus the webhost will function as a "plugin" from the applications point of view.

If anyone knows of a proper example or has some pointers for me?

Attempt a explanatory image:
[image]

In yellow the host application, in green the parts I already have. In red the thing I'm asking about. The red and green things are basically plugins.

Update2:

I'm using [DotNetCorePlugins framework](https://github.com/natemcmaster/DotNetCorePlugins) for my plugins. As a test I created an mvc webapi project (net5). Changed the application type from console to class library and changed the code in program to this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PluginTester.Contracts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PluginTester.Plugin3
{
    public class Plugin3 : IPlugin
    {
        IHostBuilder builder;

        public string GetName()
        {
            return "Web API Service";
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(new string[0]).Build().Run();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            //builder.
        }

        public IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });



        //public static void Main(string[] args)
        //{
        //    //CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        //    new Plugin3().Start();
        //}
    }
}
```

This is my "tech-test" application do excuse the naming. The start function is called when the plugin is loaded. This basically works and I can call the default weatherforecast service. The Swagger stuff for some reason does not work, but that is for later.

I had to add some assembly resolve code to the host application borrowed from here: [assembly resolving for addins](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/dec/12/loading-net-assemblies-out-of-seperate-folders). As my plugins are in subfolders of the bin folder.

Open questions

- Is this the correct way to start the webhost?
- How do I communicate from the mvc controllers with the host applications to retrieve internal status from other plugins?
- how do I stop de webhost?

Comment: First Google hit: [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). What parts of the service do you already have, and what parts of plugging ASP.NET Core into there doesn't work?

Comment: @CodeCaster Maybe read the question first? That about hosting the "website" as a service, not hosting it as a "part" of a service.

Comment: I can assure you I read it at least twice, and it seems like you want to plug an ASP.NET Core host into a Windows Service, right? Why do you think it differs whether you already have an existing Windows Service or want to create a new one? Please explain the difference to me?

Comment: I see..., it is possible I misunderstand the article you are linking. But it talks about IHostBuilder.UseWindowsService. Which I understand to be for hosting the asp.net core runtime standalone as a windows service. Not making the host a plugin part of the service. I added a little image to the question to show this. Maybe I misunderstand, but that why I am asking about pointers with a better explanation...

Comment: Perhaps you could show what your current service initialization code looks like, so we can look where you should plug in the ASP.NET Core host (Kestrel).

Comment: I did some more experiment and have updated my question accordingly.